# How to use namespace in a parent class constructor

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I have a class named `Service_B` which extends a custom service class.

This custom service class requires one single object named `Reader` in its `__construct()` in order to instantiate properly.

The parent service is defined as follow

```
namespace Vendor\Services;

abstract class Service{

    function __construct(Vendor\Services\Reader $reader){
    }
}
```

`Service_B` is defined as follow:

```
namespace Vendor\Services;    

class Service_B extends Service{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(new \Vendor\Services\Reader());
    }
}
```

`Reader` do have the following line at the top of the file:

```
use Vendor\Services;
```

Class files are organized like this:

```
Vendor/Services/Service_B.php
Vendor/Services/Reader.php
```

**Question**:
When I instantiate Service_B, I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Vendor\Services\Reader' not found
```

I don't understand why I get this error since I think I am using the proper namespaces declarations. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of your `Reader` class place:

```
//This will declare the Reader class in this namespace
namespace Vendor\Services;
```

and remove:

```
//THIS IS A WRONG DIRECTIVE: you're telling PHP to use the Vendor\Services class but it doesn't even exist     
use Vendor\Services;
```

Then modify the `Service_B` class as follow:

```
namespace Vendor\Services;    

//i think this should extend Service, as it's calling the parent constructor
class Service_B extends Service
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct( new Reader() );
    }
}
```

This way all yours 3 classes will be in the same namespace, and the `Reader` class should be found without explicit namespace prefix

Comment: Yes Service_B extends Service I haved edited the original post accordingly

Comment: Thank you, replacing 'use' by 'namespace' fixed the problem.